# How to merge two different pandas data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

*by thought is using iterate the data frame column and check for required data in another column using condition checks.
suggest is it correct or any other way.*

Comment: please refer to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for everyone's benefit and time not being wasted, could you post sample data and what you have tried so far. one sentence won't get us anywhere. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Merge, join and concatenate: look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: two data frames are didn't have any common column. but the first data frame column x data is matching with 2nd data frame of one column data but the data is in list of dictionary( one key of dict is matching with one column of 1st data frame)

Comment: df1 = [{'name': 'Anastasia', 'score': 12.5}, {'name': 'Dima', 'score': 9},   {'name': 'Katherine', 'data': 16.5}]
         df2 = [{'test': 'ram', 'data': [{'xyz': '12.5', 'abc': 'ram'} ], {'test': 'jump', 'data': [{'xyz': '9', 'abc': 'jam'}], {'test': 'bheem', 'data': [{'xyz': '16.5', 'abc': 'pim'}]] in df1 column "Score: and df2 data[xyz] are common with this reference i want to merge my data frames : can any one help

Comment: Then refactor second column in your dataframe into 2 separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at pandas [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function.

Comment: Thanks @Guillame,  tried all those, its little different case, no common column to merge. refer above example